# Need help solving an exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've tried for the last hour and a half, but I can't figure out how to solve this problem. I'd really appreciate some help.

$$\frac{50\cdot 2^x}{1+2^{-x}} = 4$$

Comment: The first thing I would do is let y= 2^x so the equation become 50y/(1+ y)= 4.  Now multiply both sides by 1+ y.  Can you solve 50y= 4(1+ y).  Can you solve that for y?  Once you have 2^x= y, taking logarithms of both sides xlog(2)= log(y).

Comment: @user247327 The resulting equation would be $50y/(1+1/y)=4$

Answer (score 5):

Guide:

$$\frac{50(2^x)}{1+2^{-x}} = 4$$

Let $y = 2^x$

$$50y= 4(1+y^{-1})$$

Multiply $y$ throughout and you should get a quadratic eqution.

After you solve for $y$ then solve for $x$.